# What type of memory module do I have - DDR3 or DDR 4 RAM?

Tags: hardware, ram

I want to buy a RAM module for my laptop. I used the `sudo lshw -short -C memory` command and I've got this [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJn9g.png). I know everything about my RAM, except the type. I can see `4GIB SODIMM Synchronous 2133 MHz`, but I don't know which one I need - `DDR3` or `DDR4`?

Information from a Google research : DDR3 specifications started at 800 MT/s (or Millions of Transfers per second) and some went as high as 2133. DDR4, meanwhile, starts at 2133 MHz.

Comment: Take a look at the current module in the notebook? It is always printed on the module itself. By the way: your BIOS should show it too.

Answer (score 13):

When you execute `sudo lshw -class memory`, you receive an information similar to this one :

```
 `*-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 18
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          product: CT102464BF160B.C16
          vendor: Conexant (Rockwell)
          physical id: 0
          serial: 118048000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 8 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 1
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
          product: CT102464BF160B.C16
          vendor: Conexant (Rockwell)
          physical id: 2
          serial: 082048000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 8 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM [empty]
          product: [Empty]
          vendor: [Empty]
          physical id: 3
          serial: [Empty]
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
```

In this example from my machine you can see that the modules are DIMM DDR3 RAM. When the command for whatever reason doesn't give you sufficient information, another option would be to look it up in the BIOS or on the module itself.
Learn more about DDR3 and DDR4 RAM here ->

[Difference Between DDR3 and DDR4](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-ddr3-and-vs-ddr4/)

Comment: I know this too, but in my case, the is no information about thy type.  In your example,  it's obvious DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz, you have DDR3 RAM with 1600 MHz frequency

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
sudo dmidecode -t memory
```

Instead of:

```
sudo lshw -class memory
```

The first command returned the type of RAM finally. The second one works fine too, but in my case there was no information about the type.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.crucial.com and enter your make & model #, and it'll tell you what kind of RAM you have/need.